# TemplateCompileException while working with array in razor

Tags: templating, razormediator

I'm having a difficult time getting the below code to work.
It's choking on the `testArray[Count] = "asdf"` statement.
How should this statement be written?

```
<ul class="product-options--list">
   @Component.Fields.product_links_rtf
   @foreach (var fields in Component.Fields.product_links)
   {
      testArray[Count] = "asdf";                    
   }
</ul>
```

Comment: What are "testArray" and "count"? please explain a little about your problem and what is the error?

Comment: I'm flagging this question for closure as off-topic because it's not really about Tridion. It's just a bug in the questioner's code, and he's found the answer. I don't think any Tridion people are going to profit by it remaining in the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My declaration of the array was incorrect.

Comment: That's not an answer that someone else can use. Could you please explain how you were declaring it wrong (ideally by including it in the question) and how to do it right (in the answer)?